# How to use LEAD function with condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, lead

I am using my query to pull back instances where one customer is buying things on multiple days. I am interested in pulling back only rows where the customer is buying the same item on different days.

My query looks like this:

```
FROM (
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by ordernumber,onlydate ORDER BY ordernumber  ) as ROW_Number2 
   FROM 
          (
          SELECT
                 Firstname
                 ,lastname
                 ,customerid
                 ,orderdate
                 ,ordernumber
                 ,producttype
                 ,
                     convert(date, orderdate) as onlydate,
             convert(time (0), orderdate)as onlytime
                 FROM sales a (nolock) 
                 JOIN product p(nolock)
                 ON a.customerid = p.customerid
                 WHERE orderdate BETWEEN '07/01/2018' AND '09/01/2018'

         )                   
          )as A
                       ) AS B
                       WHERE B.ROW_Number2=1
```

and it pulls back instances where the customer is buying things on different days, but sometimes it will show that the customer is buying different items. I think I need to use a LEAD function with a parameter on the producttype but not sure how to insert it into this query.

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Example data:

```
firstname    lastname     customerid   b.department  orderdate   producttype 
---------    ---------    ---------     ---------    ---------    ---------
 alice        johnson       1            athletic      12/7/17     shoes
 alice        johnson       1            athletic      12/8/18     headband
 john         parker        2            toiletries    12/9/18     cleaning
 john         parker        2            toiletries    12/10/18    personal
 john         parker        2            toiletries    12/10/18    cleaning
```

Desired data:

```
 firstname    lastname     customerid   b.department  orderdate  producttype 
---------    ---------    ---------     ---------    ---------    ---------
 john         parker        2            toiletries    12/9/18     cleaning
 john         parker        2            toiletries    12/10/18    cleaning
```

Would like it to only display instances where john puchased cleaning

Comment: You better show some example data and expected result

Comment: added - thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something, but I do not see the need for Windowed functions.  Why not just use an EXISTS or CROSS APPLY:

```
-- prep data
SELECT * 
into #t
FROM (values 
    ('alice' ,    'johnson',       1        ,'athletic',   '12/7/17' ,   'shoes'      ),
    ('alice' ,    'johnson',       1        ,'athletic',   '12/8/18' ,   'headband'),
    ('john'  ,    'parker' ,       2        ,'toiletries', '12/9/18' ,   'cleaning'),
    ('john'  ,    'parker' ,       2        ,'toiletries', '12/10/18',   'personal'),
    ('john'  ,    'parker' ,       2        ,'toiletries', '12/10/18',   'cleaning')
)t(firstname    ,lastname     ,customerid   ,department  ,orderdate   ,producttype )


-- output using EXISTS
SELECT 
     t.firstname    
    ,t.lastname     
    ,t.customerid   
    ,t.department  
    ,t.orderdate   
    ,t.producttype 
FROM #t t
where exists (
    SELECT * 
    FROM #t it
    where 
        it.customerid = t.customerid
    and it.producttype = t.producttype
    and it.orderdate <> t.orderdate
)


-- output using a CROSS APPLY
SELECT 
     t.firstname    
    ,t.lastname     
    ,t.customerid   
    ,t.department  
    ,t.orderdate   
    ,t.producttype 
FROM #t t
cross apply (
    SELECT *
    FROM #t it 
    where 
        it.customerid = t.customerid
    and it.producttype = t.producttype
    and it.orderdate <> t.orderdate
) ct
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . .

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(orderdate) over (partition by customerid, department, producttype order by orderdate) as prev_orderdate,
             lead(orderdate) over (partition by customerid, department, producttype order by orderdate) as lead_orderdate
      from t
     ) t
where orderdate = dateadd(day, 1, prev_orderdate) or
      orderdate = dateadd(day, -1, next_orderdate) ;
```

This does assume that there are not multiple purchases on the same day, although that could be handled with a bit more logic.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. So the reason why the query is built this was with the row number partition is because we had seen multiple purchases in the same day that definitely skewed our data.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS
 ( -- your base query
   SELECT 
        Firstname
        ,lastname
        ,customerid
        ,ordernumber
        ,department
        ,producttype
        ,convert(DATE, orderdate) AS onlydate
        ,convert(time (0), orderdate)as onlytime
   FROM sales a (nolock) 
   JOIN Product p(nolock)
   ON a.customerid = p.customerid
   WHERE orderdate BETWEEN '07/01/2018' AND '09/01/2018'
 )
,MinMaxDate AS
 ( -- adding MIN/MAX
   SELECT *
      ,MIN(onlydate) Over (PARTITION BY customerid, producttype) AS MinDate
      ,MAX(onlydate) Over (PARTITION BY customerid, producttype) AS MaxDate
   FROM UniqueDates
 )
SELECT * 
FROM TypeCount
WHERE MinDate <> MaxDate -- same product purchased on at least two days
```

Answer (score 0):

Example data to play around:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (firstname NVARCHAR(255), lastname NVARCHAR(255), customerid INT, [b.department] NVARCHAR(255), orderdate DATE, producttype NVARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @Data (firstname,lastname,customerid,[b.department],orderdate,producttype) VALUES 
     ('alice','johnson',1,'athletic','2017-07-12','shoes')
    ,('alice','johnson',1,'athletic','2018-08-12','headband')
    ,('john','parker',2,'toiletries','2018-09-12','cleaning')
    ,('john','parker',2,'toiletries','2018-10-12','personal')
    ,('john','parker',2,'toiletries','2018-10-12','cleaning')
;
```

The query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY d.customerid,d.producttype) AS [CountSameThingsDifferentDays],d.* FROM @Data d) a
WHERE a.CountSameThingsDifferentDays > 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Per your description, you provided us one table and in your original table you have two tables. I could not understand your logic clearly. Pleas show us how you do to deal with your original data.

According to my understanding, you may not use lead() to get your requirement and only add some conditions.

Describe more?

```
 -----prep data
SELECT * 
into #t
FROM (values 
    ('alice' ,    'johnson',       1        ,'athletic',   '12/7/17' ,   'shoes'      ),
    ('alice' ,    'johnson',       1        ,'athletic',   '12/8/18' ,   'headband'),
    ('john'  ,    'parker' ,       2        ,'toiletries', '12/9/18' ,   'cleaning'),
    ('john'  ,    'parker' ,       2        ,'toiletries', '12/10/18',   'personal'),
    ('john'  ,    'parker' ,       2        ,'toiletries', '12/10/18',   'cleaning')
)t(firstname    ,lastname     ,customerid   ,department  ,orderdate   ,producttype )

select * from #t where firstname='john' and producttype='cleaning'
/*
firstname lastname customerid  department orderdate producttype
--------- -------- ----------- ---------- --------- -----------
john      parker   2           toiletries 12/9/18   cleaning
john      parker   2           toiletries 12/10/18  cleaning
*/
```

Best Regards

Rachel